# Order in finite subgroup of GL(E)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, finite-groups

Given $E$ a vector space s.t. $\dim(E)=2$, and $G=\{g_1, g_2,... g_r\}$ a finite subgroup of $GL(E)$, $|G|=r$ (so $\forall g \in G, g^{r}=I$).

How to show that :
$\mathrm{rk}(g_1, ..., g_r)=3 \implies \forall g \in G, g^2=I$

I showed that $\exists a, b$ s.t. $g^2 = a \cdot g + b\cdot I$ but I'm stucked.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $\mathrm{rk}(g_1, ..., g_r)=3$?

Comment: It means $\dim(Vect(G))=1$

Comment: You mean the subspace generated by $g_1,\ldots,g_r$ in the $4$-dimensional space of linear transformations $E \rightarrow E$?

Comment: Yes (It means that its dimension is 3 and not 1, actually, sorry)

Comment: I tried to find examples of finite groups with exponent 2, but only find direct products of 2-cyclic groups. They only have 1-dimensional representations so a 2-dimensional representation is the direct sum of two 1-dimensionals, so that $dim(<g_1, \ldots, g_r>) = 2 $. Does this make sense?