# For a $G$ a finite subgroup of $\mathbb{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ of rank $3$, show that $f^2 = \textrm{Id}$ for all $f \in G$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, finite-groups

Let be $E$ a vector space such that $\dim E = 2$.

Let be $G$ a finite subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ such that $G$ generates a subalgebra $\mathcal{A}$ of $\mathcal{L}(E)$ : linear maps from $E$ to $E$ such that $\dim A = 3$.

Show that, for all $f \in G, f^2 = \textrm{Id}$, $\textrm{Id}$ being the identity map.

It is a duplicate of this unanswered question: [Order in finite subgroup of GL(E)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1946456/order-in-finite-subgroup-of-gle) ; a comment remarks that $\dim (<g_1, \ldots, g_p>) = 2$ where $G = \{ g_1, \ldots, g_p \}$ with $p = \textrm{card } G$ with no proof.

**Attempts**:

First, as $G$ is a finite subgroup, for all $f \in G$, $f^p = \textrm{Id}$.

So : $\det(f^p) = 1$, i.e. $\det(f)^p = 1$, then as determinant of a real matrix, $\det(f) \in \mathbb{R}$, so that $\det(f) = \pm 1$.

This gives us $f(f - (\textrm{tr} f) f) = \pm \textrm{Id}$ (characteristic polynomial in dimension $2$).
Then : $f^{-1} = \pm (f - (\textrm{tr} f) f)$.

What I'd like: to show that $p$ is necessarily even, so that I can have a $+\textrm{Id}$ and $\textrm{tr} f = 2$ so that I can conclude.

Now, I'm stuck.

- $p$ is necessarily even if, for example, I can show that $-\textrm{Id} \in 
  G$, so that $(-\textrm{Id})^p = \textrm{Id}$ is equivalent to $p$ even.

I might have solved it.

Here is an idea:

As $\det f = \pm 1$ and $\dim E = 2$, then $\det f = ab, (a, b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, so that $(a, b) \in \{ (1, 1), (-1, -1), (1, -1), (-1, 1) \}$. Then, there is three cases which give rise to 3 different trace values, namely: 2, -2, 0. The case 0 is trivial. 2 also, because it gives $f = \textrm{Id}$ and $-2$ is the case when $f = -\textrm{Id}$.

At the end, for all $f \in G, f^2 = \textrm{Id}$.

Comment: I don't know where you get $\det f = ab$ from, because $f$ is not necessarily diagonalizable over ${\mathbb R}$. Also you haven't used the hypothesis $\dim A = 3$. I am finding this question confusing, because the finite subgroups of ${\rm GL}(2,{\mathbb R})$ are known (basically cyclic groups of order $n$ and dihedral groups of order $2n$ for  $1,2,3,6$), and in all these examples seem to give $\dim A = 2$ or $4$. BTW it is easy to show that elements of finite order in ${\rm GL}(2,{\mathbb R})$ have order $1,2,3$ or $6$.

Comment: @DerekHolt If $\dim A = 3$, then $f$ is at least trigonalizable, so I can use $\det f = ab$, sorry that was implicit. This question may be confusing but I am using it in a proof by contradiction.